# Show number of row in mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this statement:

```
SELECT count(s.name), s.name, avg(a.rate),  @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM `avatec_objects_comments` as a, avatec_objects as s, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE a.oid =s.id and s.status=0 
GROUP BY s.name 
ORDER BY  avg(a.rate) desc, count(s.name) desc
```

This is my desired result (see numbers on side)

[image]

How can I set the rank like in the desired result above based on `count(s.name)` and `avg(a.rate)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL seems to have an issue with using variables with `group by`.  The solution is to use a subquery.  In addition, your query can be improved by using explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT cnt, name, avgrate,
       (@curRank := @curRank + 1) AS rank 
FROM (SELECT count(o.name) as cnt, o.name, avg(oc.rate) as avgrate, 
      FROM avatec_objects o JOIN
           avatec_objects_comments oc
           ON oc.oid = o.id 
      WHERE o.status = 0
      GROUP BY o.name
     ) oc CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
ORDER BY  avgrate desc, cnt desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! It's Working!

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest your query. Ordering will be done as last operation in this query, so it will always replace your ranks. Please check below:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT t1.*, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM 
  (SELECT count(s.name), s.name, avg(a.rate) 
   FROM `avatec_objects_comments` as a, avatec_objects as s
   WHERE a.oid =s.id and s.status=0 
   GROUP BY s.name 
   ORDER BY  avg(a.rate) desc, count(s.name) desc)) t1;
```

In this query you will get required data (it will be selected, grouped and ten ordered) and then it will just add ranks to data ready to read.